# Anystock - Scroller selected label colors

Tags: anychart

Is it possible to change the color of the labels inside of an anystock scroller when they are selected vs unselected?
I have chart.scroller().xAxis().labels().fontColor, is there something like chart.scroller().xAxis().labels().selectedFontColor?

Answer (score 0):

As of version 7.14.3 it is not possible. We will consider adding this in future releases.